# setText changes every QTextEdit even if specified to focus on one

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to put text into a QTextEdit in PyQT5, but every time I set the text for one text field it copies the same value into the other text fields on the same page. Even though I specified that it has to only change the contents of the QTextEdit field of which I have given the ID. Is this normal behavior, or is there a workaround? Any advice would be appreciated.

```py
class NodeUIDScanner(QObject):
    rfidTag = pyqtSignal(str)
    scanEnabled = bool

    def init(self):
        self.scanEnabled = False

    def run(self):
        self.scanEnabled = True
        dev = rfid_scanner.init('COM7') #change depending on usb port
        while self.scanEnabled:

            rfid = rfid_scanner.read(dev)

            if rfid is None:
                continue

            if 'rfid' not in rfid:
                continue

            rfid = rfid['rfid']

            self.scanEnabled = False

        self.rfidTag.emit(rfid)

    def stop(self):
        self.scanEnabled = False

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_win = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = RFIDScannerDesign.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)

        #default page on load is the create page
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageCreate)

        #nav buttons
        self.ui.buttonCreate.clicked.connect(self.showCreate)
        self.ui.buttonRead.clicked.connect(self.showRead)
        self.ui.buttonUpdate.clicked.connect(self.showUpdate)
        self.ui.buttonDelete.clicked.connect(self.showDelete)
        self.ui.read_editButton.clicked.connect(self.showEdit)

        #scan buttons
        self.ui.create_buttonScan.clicked.connect(self.scanNodeUidCreate)
        self.ui.read_buttonScan.clicked.connect(self.scanNodeUidRead)
        self.ui.update_buttonScanOld.clicked.connect(self.scanNodeUidOld)
        self.ui.update_buttonScanNew.clicked.connect(self.scanNodeUidNew)
        self.ui.delete_buttonScan.clicked.connect(self.scanNodeUidDelete)

        #submit button gives alert asking if you're sure you have the right input
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmit.clicked.connect(self.alertCreate)
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmit.clicked.connect(self.alertEdit)
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmit.clicked.connect(self.alertUpdate)
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmit.clicked.connect(self.alertDelete)

        #yes or no buttons with alert. Yes sends info to db. No keeps you on the page
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitYes.clicked.connect(self.submitCreate)
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitNo.clicked.connect(self.hideCreateAlert)

        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitYes.clicked.connect(self.submitEdit)
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitNo.clicked.connect(self.hideEditAlert)

        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitYes.clicked.connect(self.submitUpdate)
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitNo.clicked.connect(self.hideUpdateAlert)

        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitYes.clicked.connect(self.submitDelete)
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitNo.clicked.connect(self.hideDeleteAlert)

        #define QThread here so it can be used
        self.main_win.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = NodeUIDScanner()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.main_win.thread)
        self.main_win.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

    def show(self):
        self.main_win.show()

    #Functions for nav buttons to show the right page
    def showCreate(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageCreate)
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.create_alert.hide()
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    def showRead(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageRead)
        self.ui.read_editButton.show()

    def showUpdate(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageUpdate)
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.update_alert.hide()
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    def showDelete(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageDelete)
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.delete_alert.hide()
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    def showEdit(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageEdit)
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.edit_alert.hide()
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    #Threads for scanning nodeUIDs asynchronously
    def readRFID(self, rfid):
        try:
            response_rfid = database.query(IndexName='rfid-index',
                                                    KeyConditionExpression=Key('rfid').eq(rfid))
            if response_rfid['Count'] > 0:
                print('RFID already in database', rfid)
                print('Node uid:', int(response_rfid['Items'][0]['node_uid']))
                return int(response_rfid['Items'][0]['node_uid'])

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def scanNodeUidCreate(self):
        if self.ui.create_buttonScan.clicked:
            self.worker.stop()

        self.worker.rfidTag.connect(self.displayNodeCreate)

        self.main_win.thread.start()

    def scanNodeUidRead(self):
        if self.ui.read_buttonScan.clicked:
            self.worker.stop()

        self.worker.rfidTag.connect(self.displayNodeRead)

        self.main_win.thread.start()

    def scanNodeUidOld(self):
        if self.ui.update_buttonScanOld.clicked:
            self.worker.stop()

        self.worker.rfidTag.connect(self.displayNodeOld)

        self.main_win.thread.start()

    def scanNodeUidNew(self):
        if self.ui.update_buttonScanNew.clicked:
            self.worker.stop()

        self.worker.rfidTag.connect(self.displayNodeNew)

        self.main_win.thread.start()

    def scanNodeUidDelete(self):
        if self.ui.delete_buttonScan.clicked:
            self.worker.stop()

        self.worker.rfidTag.connect(self.displayNodeDelete)

        self.main_win.thread.start()

    #Slot for passing signal from worker thread to keep it asynchronous
    def displayNodeCreate(self, node):
        if self.ui.stackedWidget.currentWidget() == self.ui.pageCreate:
            self.ui.create_nodeUid.setText(str(self.readRFID(node)))
            self.ui.create_buttonScan.setChecked(False)

        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.quit()
        self.main_win.thread.wait()

    def displayNodeRead(self, node):
        if self.ui.stackedWidget.currentWidget() == self.ui.pageRead:
            self.ui.read_nodeUid.setText(str(self.readRFID(node)))
            self.ui.edit_nodeUid.setText(str(self.readRFID(node)))
            self.ui.read_buttonScan.setChecked(False)

        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.quit()
        self.main_win.thread.wait()

    def displayNodeOld(self, node):
        if self.ui.stackedWidget.currentWidget() == self.ui.pageUpdate:
            self.ui.update_nodeUidOld.setText(str(self.readRFID(node)))
            self.ui.update_buttonScanOld.setChecked(False)

        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.quit()
        self.main_win.thread.wait()

    def displayNodeNew(self, node):
        if self.ui.stackedWidget.currentWidget() == self.ui.pageUpdate:
            self.ui.update_nodeUidNew.setText(str(self.readRFID(node)))
            self.ui.update_buttonScanNew.setChecked(False)

        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.quit()
        self.main_win.thread.wait()

    def displayNodeDelete(self, node):
        if self.ui.stackedWidget.currentWidget() == self.ui.pageDelete:
            self.ui.delete_nodeUid.setText(str(self.readRFID(node)))
            self.ui.delete_buttonScan.setChecked(False)

        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.quit()
        self.main_win.thread.wait()

    #Submit button, when pressed gives alerts
    def alertCreate(self):
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmit.hide()
        self.ui.create_alert.show()
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitYes.show()
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitNo.show()

    def alertEdit(self):
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmit.hide()
        self.ui.edit_alert.show()
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitYes.show()
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitNo.show()

    def alertUpdate(self):
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmit.hide()
        self.ui.update_alert.show()
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitYes.show()
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitNo.show()

    def alertDelete(self):
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmit.hide()
        self.ui.delete_alert.show()
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitYes.show()
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitNo.show()

    #TODO add db connection
    def submitCreate(self):
        self.showCreate()
        self.ui.create_alertSucces.show()
        self.fade(self.ui.create_alertSucces)

    def submitEdit(self):
        self.showRead()
        self.ui.read_alertSucces.show()
        self.fade(self.ui.read_alertSucces)

    def submitUpdate(self):
        self.showUpdate()
        self.ui.update_alertSucces.show()
        self.fade(self.ui.update_alertSucces)

    def submitDelete(self):
        self.showDelete()
        self.ui.delete_alertSucces.show()
        self.fade(self.ui.delete_alertSucces)

    def hideCreateAlert(self):
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.create_alert.hide()
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.create_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    def hideEditAlert(self):
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.edit_alert.hide()
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.edit_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    def hideUpdateAlert(self):
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.update_alert.hide()
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.update_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    def hideDeleteAlert(self):
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmit.show()
        self.ui.delete_alert.hide()
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitYes.hide()
        self.ui.delete_buttonSubmitNo.hide()

    #fade effect for animations on labels and alerts
    def fade(self, widget):
        self.effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        widget.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)

        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.effect, b"opacity")
        self.animation.setDuration(3000)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = Main()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the error? What is the code you used to get this error? Many questions more sprang into my head after reading your question so there is a big need for clarification  from your side

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege I've added code, it's quite messy. The problem I'm facing is with the displayNodeNew and displayNodeOld functions.

Comment: @musicamante code added

Comment: @KaneS yes, it's quite messy, and has some problems. First of all, all those `if self.ui.<button>.clicked:` are wrong and make no sense: not only those are *signals* (which means that it makes no sense to use an `if` statement for them), but the "truthfulness" will always be *true*. Then, signals can be connected more than once even to the same slot/function: your code is quite convoluted, so I cannot test it, but it's possible that you're getting that result because you're continuously connecting to the related functions without disconnecting them from the previous one(s).

Comment: If you want to use the output of rfid only for a specific function (so, write it only to a specific widget), you must ensure that the signal is not (still) connected to any other function. But the fact is that the whole code has a lot of "boilerplate": all the `displayNode*` functions practically do the same thing, except for checking the current widget. A smarter choice would be to switch to the new page and set the target widgets when the button is clicked, and use a single function to set the text and set the checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time a "buttonScan" is clicked, you connect it to a slot. Signals can be connected to an indefinite number of functions, and it is also possible to connect a signal to the same function more than once.

Stopping the worker won't change anything, as the object still exists, and when the signal will be emitted every (previously) connected function will be called as well.

Since all functions do practically the same thing, a better choice is to connect the signal to a *single* function, and set the target widgets when switching between pages.

Note that there are other problems in your code, most importantly:

- `clicked` is a signal, using `if someObject.someSignal:` is pointless as it will always be considered valid, and since the function is already connected to that signal there would be no point in checking it anyway;
- calling `wait()` of an external thread in the main thread is *wrong*, since it is blocking; I won't address the issue here as it's off topic to the question;

Unfortunately, your code is quite convoluted, so I'm only providing modifications for a single page, then you have to implement the rest on your own.

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ui.create_buttonScan.clicked.connect(self.startScan)
        # ...
        self.worker.rfidTag.connect(self.rfidReceived)

    def showCreate(self):
        if self.ui.stackedWidget.currentWidget == self.ui.pageCreate:
            return
        # ...
        self.worker.stop() # just to be sure...
        self.targetField = self.ui.create_nodeUid
        self.targetCheck = self.ui.create_buttonScan

    def startScan(self):
        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.start()

    def rfidReceived(self, node):
        self.targetField.setText(str(self.readRFID(node))
        self.targetCheck.setChecked(False)

        self.worker.stop()
        self.main_win.thread.quit()
        self.main_win.thread.wait()
```

<sup>Note that more than half of your code is [*boilerplate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) just like the functions that update the text edits: they *always* do the same thing, just for different targets. This makes your code unnecessarily long and convoluted, so, prone to errors and annoying editing whenever you need to change its behavior. Since it seems clear that almost all your pages have the same interface (except for the *read* page) it's pointless to have functions that do the same thing repeated 5 times, especially considering that you're using *very similar* names that might be easily confused; each function is repeated for its 5 "targets" (the page and its buttons), that makes 30 functions, while you could just have 4 or 5. A better modularization and usage of classes will certainly be a smarter choice, will cut down your code by at least half the size, and will make debugging and maintenance much easier.</sup>